# How to uninstall a program using a version-independent name in WMIC

Tags: batch-file, wmic, winget

I was creating a batch to automate Java uninstallation:

```
wmic product where name="Java 8 Update 321 (64-bit)" call uninstall /nointeractive
```

but Oracle renamed app in WMIC as Java 8 Update **321** (64-bit). For example in the future Oracle will release new version 322, my batch will simply stop working due to the different version. It's not only name that Oracle changes every update, it also changes ID like {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180**321**F0}.

I already tried using an alternative using winget like this:

`winget install "Oracle.JavaRuntimeEnvironment"` works

`winget uninstall "Oracle.JavaRuntimeEnvironment"` doesn't work because ID is different, which was {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180**321**F0}, which has to do with version number.

Is there a way to uninstall without version number in batch?

Comment: In a [[tag:batch-file]] replace ```where name="Java 8 Update 321 (64-bit)"``` with ```Where "Name Like 'Java 8 Update%%'"```, or in [[tag:cmd]] replace it with ```Where "Name Like 'Java 8 Update%'"``` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('wmic product get description^|find "Java" ') do set "javaversion=%%b"
echo ready to delete "%javaversion%"
```

Then `wmic product where name="%javaversion%" call un...`

(That's just to set an environment variable & display it)

```
If you're feeling brave, try

for /f "delims=" %%b in ('wmic product get description^|find "Java" ') do ECHO wmic product where name="%%b" call uninstall /nointeractive
```

and remove the `echo` keyword to actually perform the uninstall.

Comment: It should be more efficient to filter directly in the WMIC.exe utility itself Magoo, rather than piping a result through find.exe too, _(as per my comment below the question itself)_.